# adding different menus in different pages in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, menubar

I'm newbie in wordpress 3.2, i successfully added pages, posts and custom links and setup a static home page. My question is-

1) I've 6 static pages, each page should have different menubars.

2) In some pages, when user clicks menubar-> popup page should appear.

Is this possible without coding php in wordpress? OR is there a way to do it in GUI/any plugins? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do some php coding for this.
First create as much as menus you want from Dashboard -> Appearance -> Menu

Then you need to register the menu on functions.php
Finally you needs to add these menu to custom template files.

Here are some tutorials to add second menu to WordPress. Repeat the same process for all 6 menus.

[Creating-a-secondary-horizontal-menu](http://reflectingthedesigner.com/wordpress/2011/01/06/creating-a-secondary-horizontal-menu-space/)

[Add Second Navigation Menu to WordPress Child Theme](http://www.fix-css.com/2011/06/how-to-add-second-navigation-menu-to-child-wp-theme/)

[Adding secondary menu to wordpress template](https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=adding+secondary+menu+to+wordpress+template)

Start working on it and come back if you have any issues. Cheers !!!